# How to Mock HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to Mock HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath in one of unit tests using Moq framework. It is always giving null, can somebody please guide me to moq this one.

Comment: In this post found the way to handle mocking a static method http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.in/2011/03/mocking-static-methods-for-unit-testing.html

Comment: This is already answered here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416362/mock-static-property-with-moq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock static property with moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416362/mock-static-property-with-moq)