# How can I mock this static method

Tags: c#, moq

I have this code:

```
public static bool IsValidVoucher(string id)
{
    //read tsv files
    var temp1 = AppData.GetAppData("stringval");            
    // code that need to be tested        
    return true;        
}
```

And I like to create unit test, but how can I mock `AppData.GetAppData("stringval")` to whatever I want the value is, so I can test the rest of code.

The AppData class is:

```
public class AppData
{
    public static object GetAppData(string name)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding 'AppData.GetAppData' you could inject a class which does the reading of the AppData and then in your unit test, mock that class and setup the return value you need.

Comment: With Moq not possible without further changes of the source code. But with  [Typemock's Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-features/test-the-un-testable/fake-static-methods.html) it is possible. However Isolator is not free.

Comment: And [here](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.de/2011/03/mocking-static-methods-for-unit-testing.html) some more info about mocking static methods. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864076/mocking-static-methods) answer from SO. HTH

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mock static property with moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416362/mock-static-property-with-moq)

Comment: I've dropped my answer because I believe that it won't help in this scenario. Anyway now you know that expression trees are there to help a lot!

Answer (score 12):

Static methods cannot be mocked **in an easy way**. You basically have two choices:

1. If you own the `AppData` class, change the implementation to implement an interface (e.g. `IAppData`) and remove the `static` modifier on the `GetAppData` method so you can mock it.

   ```
   public interface IAppData
   {
       object GetAppData(string id);
   }

   public class AppData : IAppData
   {
       public object GetAppData(string id) {}
   }

   public class Foo
   {
       private readonly IAppData _appData;

       public Foo(IAppData appData)
       {
           _appData = appData;
       }

       public bool IsValidVoucher(string id)
       {
           // Call through object instance instead for class reference
           var temp1 = _appData.GetAppData("stringval");
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you do not own the `AppData` class, use a wrapper class (e.g. `AppDataWrapper`)  that implements an interface and call that method from `IsValidVoucher` instead:

   ```
   public interface IAppData
   {
       object GetAppData(string id);
   }

   public class AppDataWrapper : IAppData
   {
       public object GetAppData(string id)
       {
           return AppData.GetAppData(id);
       }
   }

   public class Foo
   {
       private readonly IAppData _appData;

       public Foo(IAppData appData)
       {
           _appData = appData;
       }

       public bool IsValidVoucher(string id)
       {
           var temp1 = _appData.GetAppData("stringval");
       }
   }
   ```

You can then unit test `Foo` using Moq (using xunit as an example here):

```
public class FooTests
{
    private readonly IAppData _mockAppData;

    public FooTests()
    {
        var mockAppData = new Mock<IAppData>();
        mockAppData.Setup(m => m.GetAppData(It.IsAny<string>)).Returns("my test value");
        _mockAppData = mockAppData.Object;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void IsValidVoucher_ValidAppData_Returns()
    {
        var foo = new Foo(_mockAppData);
        // Unit test foo.IsValidVoucher
    }
}
```

Comment: You said static methods can't be mocked... See my answer ;P Maybe it's a crazy idea, but it works!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, I should say static method cannot be mocked **in an easy way** ;) Edited for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think everyone's comments so far is technically correct - using something like `RhinoMocks` or `Moq`, you really can't mock static methods in a facile, straightforward manner.

But using `Moles`, you definitely can. So if you have significant (currently) untestable code that reside within static methods, I think you should be looking into Moles.

(This link is a bit dated but I still find it helpful)
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molesmanual.pdf

(Key text)

> Moles can be used to detour any .NET method, including non-virtual and static methods in sealed types.

How it works: Suppose you have a typical situation like this:

```
public static class SomeStaticClass
{
    public static int SomeStaticMethod(string s)
    {
        return "Static method called: " + s;
    }
}

public class SomeInstanceClass
{
    public string SomeInstanceMethod(string s)
    {
        return SomeStaticClass.SomeStaticMethod(s);
    }
}
```

Using Moles, your test code would look like this:

```
[TestMethod()]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void ShouldBeAbleToTestStaticMethod()
{
    var instance = new SomeInstanceClass();
    var testValue = instance.SomeInstanceMethod("Some test string");
    SomeStaticClass.SomeStaticMethod = (s) => "Moled you! " + s;
    Assert.That(testValue, Is.EqualTo("Moled you! Some test string"); // sorry, this has code smell, lol
}
```

Of course you need to set up Moles into your test project, so be sure to look it up - lots of web resources to help you on your way.

Some helpful posts:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798308.aspx

http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2011/03/mocking-static-methods-for-unit-testing.html

https://wannabeegeek.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/unit-testing-made-easy-with-moles-part-i/

Comment: I think you should at least show some code in your answer to show how Moles can help unit testing static methods instead of simply posting links to various resources.

Comment: Is Moles still supported/available? The site seems to state that Fakes will replace it, and the assumable download link only direct me to a list where Moles isn't there.  
I may have missed the download link perhaps?

Comment: Here's current (VS 2017) docs on MS Fakes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes Unfortunately, Fakes is only available with the Enterprise SKU of Visual Studio: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/ As for Moles, it appears that it was last supported in VS 2010: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/moles-isolation-framework-for-net/